# Mobile version of a website showing up on my desktop google search

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, 302-redirect, rel-canonical, rel-alternate

I search certain keywords in desktop google search and mobile version of my website shows up, vise versa.

I use some methods to solve this problem:

- use `<link rel="alternate">` and `<link rel="canonical">` to map desktop and mobile version web page respectively.
- use 301 redirect instead of 302 redirect when desktop webpage url redirect to mobile webpage url, vise versa.

Are these correct methods to solve this problem? Are there any better idea? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to see if the engine is noticing and updating (it can be slow) then add it to your sitemap and submit via search console. Those are usually processed same day, and you'd see the results tomorrow.